# Extract and compare discriminated union constructors

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, f#, parser-combinators, discriminated-union

Given the following types:

```
type Pos = {line:int; col:int}
let Pos line col = {line = line; col = col}

type Token =
    | ADD of Pos
    | INT of Pos * int

let ts = [INT (Pos 1 1, 4);ADD (Pos 1 2);INT (Pos 1 3, 7)]

type Parser<'a> = Parser of (Token list -> 'a option * Token list)

let run p ts = let (Parser pfun) = p in pfun ts
```

When writing a function that checks if the first token in a list is of a certain token type such as:

```
let token (tok: Token) : Parser<Token> = Parser <| fun lst ->
    match lst with
    | [] -> None, lst
    | t::ts -> if t = tok then Some t, ts else None, lst
```

Is there a way to generalize this such that the parameter `tok` can simply be any of the *constructors* of `Token`, i.e. `ADD` or `INT`, and without the parameters given to those constructors?

In that way, the function `token` can then be run as `run (token ADD) ts` instead of `run (token (ADD (Pos 1 1))) ts`.

What I've tried so far is to use `GetType()`, through which I can get the constructor name as a string for the current token `t` being checked through the following:

```
t.GetType().Name     // Output: "INT" or "ADD" as strings
```

However, if I just pass the constructor `INT` as the `tok` parameter to `token`, `tok.GetType().Name` does not result as `"INT"` as the constructor `INT` is of type `Pos * int -> Token`...

Possibly to make the above `GetType()` based idea work, a solution would be to find a way to convert `INT` or `ADD` to the strings `"INT"` or `"ADD"` respectively.

Comment: can you pass a "match" statement rather than a "token"? Then you would define a function that matches each token type.

Answer (score 1):

I may have not understood.

You can define and pass a matcher

```
let matchAdd = function
    | ADD p as t -> Some t
    | _ -> None
let matchInt = function
    | INT _ as t -> Some t
    | _ -> None

let token2 matcher : Parser<Token> = Parser <| fun lst ->
    match lst with
    | [] -> None, lst
    | t::ts -> 
        match (matcher t) with 
        | Some t -> Some t, ts
        | None -> None, lst
```

?

Comment: In reality there's a very large number of `Token` cases/constructors, so I'm trying to find a way to generalize it and not have to manually write a function or match case for each `Token` constructor

Comment: you could have a type for each token, and then embed it in the data constructor, and then pass the type of the token in, it would all be typesafe, and no nasty reflection, but its a cost still...you can also use a tagless encoding...which is basically a bit like a visitor/factory...but I think you'd end up with something like I've posted above